# Swift object to reference itself (without optionals)

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an object class that contain reference to self or another object:

```
class MyObject 
{
    let owner: MyObject

    init(owner: MyObject) {
        self.owner = owner;
    }
}

class RootObject : MyObject
{
    init() {
        self.owner = self
    }
}

var root = RootObject()
var child = MyObject(root)

// child.owner == root
// child.owner.owner == root
```

Is it possible to modify this code and implement my idea without use of optionals?

Comment: Can you explain what you are after in more detail? I see you want a solution without optionals but what you have at the moment does not use optionals does it?

Comment: yes, it's not working either.

Comment: The goal is to make sure all of my objects have "owner" property, which would point to an object and my problem is - how do I add the first object as there are no other objects to point to.

Comment: I've seen `let owner: MyObject!` syntax, is that something that could help?